# How can I move a turtle as close as possible to a certain patch?

Tags: netlogo

I have a single blue patch and would like to move a turtle to the closest, empty patch to it. The only way I can think of doing this is using in-radius in a loop, increasing the radius size by one each time, but is there a better way?

Comment: Thats quite a vague question title.

Answer (score 1):

```
globals [bluey]

to setup
  ca
  ask one-of patches [set pcolor blue set bluey self]
  ask n-of 250 patches [sprout 1]
end

to-report nearest-empty [#patch]
  report min-one-of 
         [other (patches with [not any? turtles-here])] of #patch
         [distance #patch]
end

to test
  setup
  ;the following fails if all patches occupied
  ;(can add a test for nobody)
  ask nearest-empty bluey [set pcolor red]
end
```

Comment: The code is currently not testing for the "empty" condition. `nearest-empty` should be something like `report min-one-of other patches with [ not any? turtles-here ] [ distance myself ]`

Comment: @NicolasPayette Agreed.  (But that only affects `test`.)  Based on the problem description, I assumed fewer turtles than patches.

Comment: I don't understand your reply; it seems to me like `nearest-empty` would be the right place to check that the nearest patch is indeed empty. And when I ran your code, the red patch sometimes ended up being occupied, which I think violates the requirements.

Comment: @NicolasPayette Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment, because I did not realize I had somehow posted a previous version of the answer.  Fixed.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Unrelated: may I ask why you're using `#` as a prefix in the `#patch` parameter? I'm assuming it's a convention of yours, but I find it confusing since `#` very strongly evokes a number, and this is an agent reference. Why not `target-patch` or something like that?

Comment: @NicolasPayette Two reasons.  First, because of NetLogo's scoping conventions (no name masking), I want to use naming conventions for formal parameters and local variables that assure no conflict with global names.  (I also like formal parameters to be distinguishable from names declared locally.)  Second, hashmark ids for formal parameters are common in some languages, so I find it a natural association.  All in all, it is just as you said, a convention.